Need help verifying definition of representation isomorphism.
[G-Linear Map] For two representations $V$ and $W$ of group $G$, a vector space map $\varphi:V \rightarrow W$ such that the group action is preserved, $g\phi(v)=\phi(gv)$ for all $g\in G$ and $v\in V$, is called a $G$-linear map.
[Representation Isomorphism] Let $G$ be a group and $V,W$ be vector spaces over the same field. Let $\rho:G \to GL(V)$ and $\rho': G\to GL(W)$ be representations, then $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are said to be isomorphic representations if there exist a bijective $G$-linear map from $V$ to $W$.
Could someone help verify whether these definitions are correct? Also, in practice, this will mean that I have to

Find a map $\phi:V \to W$,
Show that map is linear,
Show that map is bijective and
Show that $g\phi(v)=\phi(gv)$ for all $g\in G$ and $v\in V$.


I would say yes they are correct, but the more important question(s) might be: 1. What is the source? 2. Why do you doubt it?

ah okay thanks for verifying. The first definition is from fulton and harris, the second i got from wikipedia, i couldn't find the meaning of isomorphism inside the text so I just wanted to be sure
